# Delete all calendars and contacts in iOS

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, contacts, calendar

I'd like to delete all calendars and contacts on an iPod Touch with iOS 5.0.1 without affecting calendars and contacts in OS X.

I've read guides that instruct to disable calendars for accounts in order to delete calendars. In my case none of my accounts have ever had calendars enabled. Calendars have only been transferred by cable using iTunes.

Can this be done without a third party app? If not, what would be needed to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete an Existing Calendar :

- In iPhone Calendar, tap on the **Calendars** button at the top-left of the iPhone Calendar display.
- Tap on the **Edit** button at the *top-left* of the Calendars display.
- Tap on the calendar you wish to delete.
- *Scroll to reveal* the **Delete Calendar** button at the bottom of the Edit Calendar display and tap on it.
- *Confirm* the deletion by tapping on **Delete Calendar** in the confirmation display.
- Tap Done at the top-left of the Edit Calendars display.
- Tap Done at the top-right of the Calendars display to return to the main display.

---

Delete a contact :

- **Select** the contact's name.
- Click on the **"edit"** button in the upper right hand corner.
- **Scroll down** and select delete.

If you want to delete contacts **in bulk** you can use these apps :

- Paid :

  - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contactdel-delete-multiple/id399148990?mt=8
  - how to : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHn6ABEDk1o
- Free :

  - Download the app **'Groups'** by Qbix
  - Link : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/groups/id407855546?mt=8
  - As soon as you open the groups app it has all your contacts.
  - You can tap multiple contacts (a red dot to the left of each one) and
    then at the top on the right there is a little white arrow that says
    "actions".
  - Tap on that & you can delete, copy, or e-mail all of the
    selected contact at once.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Now only the contacts remain to be dealt with.

Comment: Edited the post how to delete a contact. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Is there not a way to do this without purchasing an app?

Comment: Yes there is : see edit.

Comment: Excellent. It was even easier as there was a **Select All** option. I feel gratitude for your help.